# Getting UPN or AAD of user messaging a Teams bot

Tags: python-3.x, botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a bot using the provided Microsoft `echo bot` example and am trying to simply get the incoming user's `AAD Object ID`.

I've tried a couple of the snippets below, but at most they seem to return the ID of the bot/channel itself.  I tried using the Graph API, but I can't do a lookup against it because I don't have a UPN of the user either.  My understanding is that this happening because the Bot is using a `Channel Account`.  Is there some other way to approach this?

And oddly enough, when I test the bot on the `dev.botframework.com` web GUI, it replies with the information fine.

`aad = user_data.aadObjectId if hasattr(user_data, "aadObjectId") else None`

`aad = getattr(user_data, 'aadObjectId', None)`

`upn = await get_aad_object_id(user_data.user_principal_name)`

Comment: You can get AAD Object id of the user interacting with bot via turnContext as below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSnTb.png

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT If I understand correctly, isn't that what I tried, based on my code above?  It returned a really long value that was definitely not the AAD of the user.  It was the identity of the `Channel Account` I believe.

Comment: If you will check the screenshot provided, we are getting AadObjectId in turnContext.